# Entity Framework/Linq Loop Optimization Issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this code I have written below for a school project and I'm having difficulty optimizing the loop to run faster. To make it easier to read, I have a loop that creates a buy transaction for each stock in the top 10 spots in a table called Ratings. The rest of the code I'm getting information for the stock price and other relevant info and using that to create a buy transaction and then I'm saving the data to the ef model. I could really use some constructive criticism on ways to make this loop run faster and/or more efficient. Thanks!

```
    public static void createTransactions(string portfolioName, string risk)
    {
        try
        {
            OoplesFinanceDBModel model = new OoplesFinanceDBModel();
            IQueryable<StockRating> ratings = model.StockRatings.AsQueryable();
            decimal startingCash = 2000;
            decimal startingMargin = 2000;
            decimal currentCash = startingCash;
            decimal currentMargin = startingMargin;
            decimal purchaseTotal = 0;
            int portfolioID = model.Portfolios.Where(i => i.Name == portfolioName).FirstOrDefault().ID;

            switch (risk)
            {
                case "low":
                    ratings = ratings.OrderByDescending(i => i.LongRating);
                    break;
                case "medium":
                    ratings = ratings.OrderByDescending(i => i.MediumRating);
                    break;
                case "high":
                    ratings = ratings.OrderByDescending(i => i.ShortRating);
                    break;
                default:
                    ratings = ratings.OrderByDescending(i => i.MediumRating);
                    break;
            }

            // now add the top 10 stocks in each risk to each portfolio
            // start with low risk
            foreach (StockRating rating in ratings.Where(j => j.MarginEnabled == true).Take(10))
            {
                Transactions transaction = new Transactions();
                transaction.Symbol = rating.Symbol;
                transaction.Market = rating.Market;
                transaction.PortfolioID = portfolioID;
                transaction.TransactionType = "Buy";
                transaction.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                transaction.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;

                // finally set the quantity and price that we are buying based on the latest price
                switch (transaction.Market)
                {
                    case "amex":
                        transaction.Price = model.DailyAmexDatas.Where(i => i.Symbol == transaction.Symbol).OrderByDescending(j => j.Date).FirstOrDefault().AdjustedClose;
                        break;
                    case "nasdaq":
                        transaction.Price = model.DailyNasdaqDatas.Where(i => i.Symbol == transaction.Symbol).OrderByDescending(j => j.Date).FirstOrDefault().AdjustedClose;
                        break;
                    case "nyse":
                        transaction.Price = model.DailyNyseDatas.Where(i => i.Symbol == transaction.Symbol).OrderByDescending(j => j.Date).FirstOrDefault().AdjustedClose;
                        break;
                    default:
                        transaction.Price = model.DailyGlobalDatas.Where(i => i.Symbol == transaction.Symbol).OrderByDescending(j => j.Date).FirstOrDefault().AdjustedClose;
                        break;
                }

                // set the quanity that we are able to buy
                transaction.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(((startingCash + startingMargin) / 10) / transaction.Price);
                purchaseTotal = transaction.Quantity * transaction.Price;

                // now update the remaining cash and/or margin
                if ((purchaseTotal > currentMargin) || purchaseTotal > currentCash)
                {
                    if (purchaseTotal > currentMargin)
                    {
                        currentCash = currentCash - (purchaseTotal - currentMargin);
                        currentMargin = 0;
                    }
                    if (purchaseTotal > currentCash)
                    {
                        // get the amount of price and find out how many shares you need to take away
                        transaction.Quantity -= Convert.ToInt32((purchaseTotal - currentCash) / transaction.Price);
                        purchaseTotal = transaction.Quantity * transaction.Price;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    currentMargin = currentMargin - purchaseTotal;
                }

                model.Transactions.Add(transaction);
                Console.WriteLine(transaction.Symbol + " added to the " + portfolioName + " Portfolio");
            }

            // now set the remaining cash and margin
            Portfolios portfolio = model.Portfolios.Where(i => i.ID == portfolioID).FirstOrDefault();
            portfolio.CurrentCash = currentCash;
            portfolio.CurrentMargin = currentMargin;

            // save everything
            model.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `model.Portfolios.Where(i => i.Name == portfolioName).FirstOrDefault().ID;` Why do people use `FirstOrDefault` when they don't want `OrDefault`? What will `OrDefault` return? What are you going to achieve by getting the `ID` of `null`?

Comment: I got in the habit of using that because with threading I noticed that missing the default would cause issues or errors. In the method where I call this method from, I create the portfolios first so I know that it won't return null @ta.speot.is

Comment: *I create the portfolios first so I know that it won't return null* Then call `First` or `Single`. Semantically `OrDefault` is saying *there might not be anything there*. Why type `OrDefault`?

Comment: @ta.speot.is Ok I can change that. Do you have any other suggestions on how I can optimize?

Comment: hint: split into more methods. Easier to read code and better stacktraces.

Comment: @Yoeri I can start doing that

Comment: Here's another hint - don't ever do catches like `catch (Exception ex)` as they just make your code harder to debug.

Comment: @Enigmativity How should I do catches then?

Comment: I see a few unnecessary expenses (1) Creating a new DBModel instance for each call. (2) Re-querying SockRatings for each call. (3) Re-querying for portfolioId for each call. (4) Querying the Market values in each call. These are all things that might be refactored out of the "createTransactions" method and passed in instead. One benefit of such a change would be the ability to query rate/market information at a different frequency that executing the transactions (or not, but with this change you could). You could also easily convert the price lookups into a dictionary.

Comment: @user3610374 - You generally should only catch **specific** exceptions that are **truly** exceptional from which you want to cleanly recover - like running out of hard drive space. If you remove the `Exception` try/catches you are likely to write better code.

Comment: @Atoms I changed the first 2 items that you pointed out but I'm afraid I lost you on the other 2 items. I'm not sure how to go about accomplishing those with my code. Do you perhaps have any pointers?

Comment: @Enigmativity I was taught to always use the catch all in case I miss a regular exception but I will try to change that in my future code. Old habits die hard I think they say

Comment: @user3610374 - Whoever taught you that should be shot. It's one of the quickest ways to introduce hard to track down bugs to your code.